# How to debug authentication failures?

Tags: raspbian, active-directory, sssd

I have a Raspberry Pi that I have connected to our AD domain using realm. It is using `sssd-ad` to perform user authentication.
All accounts in the child domain to which the Pi is joined worked. However some accounts from the parent domain do not work, but some do work.

So far all I am seeing is the following errors in `/var/log/auth.log`.

```
Nov  3 14:13:03 pi-ncb234 lightdm: pam_sss(lightdm:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=:0 ruser= rhost= user=user_name@domain
Nov  3 14:13:03 pi-ncb234 lightdm: pam_sss(lightdm:auth): received for user user_name@domain: 10 (User not known to the underlying authentication module)
```

Are there any tools that will allow me to see how it is searching for user_name which does exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In `sssd.conf`, under your domain block, add a `debug_level` statement.  Debug levels range from 1 to 9, where 1 is the least verbose logging level and 9 is the most verbose.  I like to use 6 for debugging purposes.

For instance, if you have the following domain block in your config:

```
[domain/MY_DOMAIN]
debug_level = 6
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
...
```

Then the logs you are looking for will appear in `/var/log/sss/sssd_MY_DOMAIN.log` after reloading SSSD.